# "Too many values to unpack" while getting Django form out of POST request

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to get some data out of a form and filter results based on that. If I do stuff messy way (getting it directly out of the request) it works, the legit Django way (commented) - doesn't. I'm constantly getting the “Too many values to unpack” exception. What may be the problem?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print request.POST
    entries = entries.filter(date__year=request.POST['year'])
    #spanform = SpanForm(request.POST)
    #print spanform
    #if spanform.is_valid():
    #   cd = spanform.cleaned_data
    #   if cd['year']:
    #       entries = entries.filter(date__year=cd['year'])
```

Here is the code of the form:

```
class SpanForm(forms.Form):

    year = forms.ChoiceField(label="")

    def __init__(self, years, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SpanForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if years:
            self.fields['year'].choices = years
```

So, when I test the following chunk:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    #print request.POST
    #entries = entries.filter(date__year=request.POST['year'])
    spanform = SpanForm(request.POST)

    if spanform.is_valid():
       cd = spanform.cleaned_data
       if cd['year']:
           entries = entries.filter(date__year=cd['year'])
```

I get the following trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/entries/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'core')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/wswld/Code/calc/core/templates/entries.html, error at line 9
   too many values to unpack
   1 : {% extends "dashboard.html" %}


   2 : {% load staticfiles %}


   3 : 


   4 : {% block tab %}


   5 : 


   6 : <form action="." method="post">


   7 : {% csrf_token %}


   8 :         <table>


   9 :              {{form.as_p}} 


   10 :         </table>


   11 :         <input type="submit" value="Apply" />


   12 : </form>


   13 : 


   14 : <table>


   15 : {% for entry in data %}


   16 : <tr>


   17 :     <td>


   18 :         <a href="./{{ entry.uuid }}/">


   19 :             <img src="{% static "permalink.png" %}"  height="15" width="15"></img>


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/wswld/Code/calc/core/views.py" in dashboard
  82.     return render(request, '%s.html' % tab, {'tab': tab, 'data': data, 'form': spanform})
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  169.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render
  88.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  585.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  735.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  789.                             current = current()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in as_p
  241.             errors_on_separate_row = True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in _html_output
  186.                     'field': six.text_type(bf),
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  425.         return self.as_widget()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
  475.         return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  504.         options = self.render_options(choices, [value])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/widgets.py" in render_options
  528.         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):

Exception Type: ValueError at /entries/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Add your form code and the stacktrace of the error so we can see which line(s) are causing the error.

Comment: Added everything as requested.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with variable length of arguments. What happens if you change `super(SpanForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` with `super(SpanForm, self ).__init__(args, kwargs)` ?

Comment: Nothing changes much. I'm still getting the error, seemingly in the same place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not passing in the years parameter on the post condition in your view. You're passing the request.POST dictionary for the years parameter. You can either pop the years parameter out of `kwargs` in the form, or pass in `None` in the view.

```
class SpanForm(forms.Form):

    year = forms.ChoiceField(label="")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        years = kwargs.pop('years', None)
        super(SpanForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if years:
            self.fields['year'].choices = years
```

or

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    spanform = SpanForm(None, request.POST)

    if spanform.is_valid():
       cd = spanform.cleaned_data
       if cd['year']:
           entries = entries.filter(date__year=cd['year'])
```

Comment: First way yelds "'list' object has no attribute 'get'" and the second doesn't seem to work as it ignores the filter whatsoever. Just nothing changes on POST.

Comment: Now, as I fixed and tested it, seems like pretty dumb mistake. I just needed to pass it the list of years. Thank you for your answer and patience.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Sometimes a pair of fresh eyes is all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SpanForm(forms.Form):

    year = forms.ChoiceField(label="")

    def __init__(self, years, *args, **kwargs): # here you have 'years' parameter.
        super(SpanForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        if years:
            self.fields['year'].choices = years

if request.method == 'POST':
    spanform = SpanForm(request.POST) # where is your 'years' parameter? Now you have request.POST in 'years' variable from __init__ from SpanForm class.

    if spanform.is_valid():
       cd = spanform.cleaned_data
       if cd['year']:
           entries = entries.filter(date__year=cd['year'])
```

Comment: Thank you. schillingt has already made the source of my problems clear to me, but thanks for your answer.